# Clean way to scroll

Tags: java, android

I want my activity to be scrolled every time it is displayed. 
I use this code :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    ViewTreeObserver vto = maxButton.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                maxButton.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                float y = maxButton.getY();
                findViewById(R.id.map_activity_scrollview).scrollTo(0, (int) (y - 2*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/3));

            }
        });

    ConstraintLayout cl = findViewById(R.id.map_activity_constraint);
    Button b = new Button(this);
    cl.addView(b); // triggers the listener
    cl.removeView(b);

    super.onResume();
}
```

Without adding the button it works only the first time the activity is displayed. 
That's why I artificially add and remove a button.

Is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If by "displayed" you mean `onResume` and based on your code I assume you do, why don't you give this a shot:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    maxButton.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float y = maxButton.getY();
            findViewById(R.id.map_activity_scrollview).scrollTo(0, (int) (y - 2*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/3));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad. I meant displayed on the screen, i.e. when the user can see it.

Comment: With your suggestion, on the first display on the screen, the user sees to top of the screenview and then it's scrolled. I'd like to avoid this.
After that, it works perfectly : it's already scrolled when the user sees the activity.

Comment: I'm that case you should avoid using `onResume` and keep your code in `onCreate`. Using `onGlobalLayout` there is a good idea to make sure your view is laid out.

Comment: The problem is that maxButton is dynamic and onCreate is called just once when my application runs (my activity lools like Candy Crush's map, buttons are used to lauch levels and when you clear a level maxButton changes)

Comment: So in that case why don't you use another view which is persistent. Like your scroll view or something else.

Comment: What do you mean by persistent view ?
My xml file looks like this :
<Scrollview>
  <ConstrainLayout>
     <Button>
         ....
     <Button>
   </ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
maxButton is dynamially set to one of the buttons

Comment: I mean some view which always holds a reference to a particular view that will not get changed during your activity life time.